# Videos are not playing in Chromium of Node web kit

Tags: javascript, chromium, node-webkit

I an running my application (javascript app) in chromium browser using node web kit. But Videos are not playing. I used various players like HTML5 Video player, video js player and Dash player. 
Can anyone please tell me how can I play video in chromium.

Comment: Players are not loading in Node web Kit Chromium. Please help.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Actually Chromium does not support Flash.  So By mentioned player we can not run videos there.